# Generate records from Json schema

Tags: java, maven, record, java-14

For many of my projects I like to use the `org.jsonschema2pojo.jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin` maven plugin in order to generate some POJO class from a json schema file. This works great and saves me from writing boiler plate code.

However, I often treat these classes as final and immutable so I would like the ability to generate Java records instead so I can enforce those restrictions and get the performance enhancement that comes along with records. I've gone through the [documentation](https://joelittlejohn.github.io/jsonschema2pojo/site/1.2.1/generate-mojo.html) and the [GitLab repo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo) but I don't see any way to do this with this particular plugin.

Is there something I've missed or is there another plugin or library that offers this ability?

Edit: Assume I've done my research and Java records are in fact what I want/need. I don't want mutability, I don't want extendability, I'm okay with exposing member fields, I want improved performance on comparison operations (.equals), and I want to leverage pattern matching.

Comment: Honestly, I would just use Lombok and create the POJO objects. Records should not be abused. They should realistically only have a few fields. If the object has over 10 fields on it, I would avoid using a record.

Comment: I already have the schema files and generated for pojo classes which include the jackson annotations. I'm not interested in removing the plug in and writing the code myself with lombok.

Comment: There is already a request to add `record` support here: [Issue #1405](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/1405)

Comment: Good looks my friend

Answer (score -2):

I would avoid records, not only because they should only store a few values, but because they do not have the same level of control as a traditional class.

The following article breaks this all down:

> https://www.baeldung.com/java-record-vs-lombok

With Jackson's `@JsonProperty` annotation, you can tell the serializer/deserializer how to map each key to the appropriate field.

If you generate the class stubs and add in some Lombok, you can simplify this process.

The following JSON:

```json
/** https://json.org/example.html */
{
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
      "title": "S",
      "GlossList": {
        "GlossEntry": {
          "ID": "SGML",
          "SortAs": "SGML",
          "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
          "Acronym": "SGML",
          "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
          "GlossDef": {
            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
            "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
          },
          "GlossSee": "markup"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Get converted to the following shapes:

```java
package org.example.json;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Data;

public class GenerateClasses {
    private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ClassLoader classLoader = GenerateClasses.class.getClassLoader();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("glossary.json")) {
            Root root = om.readValue(is, Root.class);
            System.out.println(root); // Object::toString
            System.out.println(om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read JSON");
        }
    }

    @Data
    public static class Glossary {
        private String title;
        @JsonProperty("GlossDiv")
        private GlossDiv glossDiv;
    }

    @Data
    public static class GlossDef {
        private String para;
        @JsonProperty("GlossSeeAlso")
        private List<String> glossSeeAlso; /* Changed from ArrayList */
    }

    @Data
    public static class GlossDiv {
        private String title;
        @JsonProperty("GlossList")
        private GlossList glossList;
    }

    @Data
    public static class GlossEntry {
        @JsonProperty("ID")
        private String id; /* Manually changed from 'iD' */
        @JsonProperty("SortAs")
        private String sortAs;
        @JsonProperty("GlossTerm")
        private String glossTerm;
        @JsonProperty("Acronym")
        private String acronym;
        @JsonProperty("Abbrev")
        private String abbrev;
        @JsonProperty("GlossDef")
        private GlossDef glossDef;
        @JsonProperty("GlossSee")
        private String glossSee;
    }

    @Data
    public static class GlossList {
        @JsonProperty("GlossEntry")
        private GlossEntry glossEntry;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Root {
        private Glossary glossary;
    }
}
```

I generated the code above using the following tool:

> https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo (choose JSON > Java)

I added Lombok `@Data` annotations, made all fields `private`, and modified fields where noted.

---

### Jackson + Records Caveat

Please note that Jackson versions below 2.11.4 have trouble with deserializing JSON with records:

> https://dev.to/brunooliveira/practical-java-16-using-jackson-to-serialize-records-4og4

The following modified program (from above) uses records instead of classes mized with Lombok. It no longer depends on Lombok.

```java
package org.example.json;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class GenerateClasses {
    private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ClassLoader classLoader = GenerateClasses.class.getClassLoader();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("glossary.json")) {
            Root root = om.readValue(is, Root.class);
            System.out.println(root); // Object::toString
            System.out.println(om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read JSON");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public record Glossary (
        String title,
        @JsonProperty("GlossDiv")
        GlossDiv glossDiv
    ) {}

    public record GlossDef (
        String para,
        @JsonProperty("GlossSeeAlso")
        List<String> glossSeeAlso /* Changed from ArrayList */
    ) {}

    public record GlossDiv (
        String title,
        @JsonProperty("GlossList")
        GlossList glossList
    ) {}

    public record GlossEntry (
        @JsonProperty("ID")
        String id, /* Manually changed from 'iD' */
        @JsonProperty("SortAs")
        String sortAs,
        @JsonProperty("GlossTerm")
        String glossTerm,
        @JsonProperty("Acronym")
        String acronym,
        @JsonProperty("Abbrev")
        String abbrev,
        @JsonProperty("GlossDef")
        GlossDef glossDef,
        @JsonProperty("GlossSee")
        String glossSee
    ) {}

    public record GlossList (
        @JsonProperty("GlossEntry")
        GlossEntry glossEntry
    ) {}

    public record Root (
        Glossary glossary
    ) {}
}
```

If you encounter the following exception, you will need to update your Jackson dependency:

> `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException`: Cannot construct instance of `org.example.json.GenerateClasses$Root` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
>   at [Source: (`BufferedInputStream`); line: 2, column: 3]

Comment: I'm trying to avoid writing boiler plate code.

Comment: @JoeCaruso POJO are not boilder-plate code. Only having to write the accessors (getters), mutators (setters), toString, equals, hashCode, builders, etc... is the boilerplate. The classes above define only the fields needed with some additional annotations. This is the most concise code required. Lombok is a very powerful library that is pretty much an industry standard for the Java development community.

Comment: The plugin I am using already does everything I need and doesn't require me to add in @Data annotations. You solution requires me to first generate the code in src AND manually add in lombok annotations. What I looking for is a way to generate records so I get the performance benefits for operations like .equals() along with pattern matching.